# How to access git hub private packages

Tags: github, npm

> I want to access Github Private packages through npm install but it is showing me this package is not found in npm registry but i have git token for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First we need to generate a token from Github account inside setting or choose developer option then click and generate .
> And use this token in npm from your Command line as

npm login --scope=@OWNER --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com

> Username: USERNAME

> Password: TOKEN //Github generated token

> Email: PUBLIC-EMAIL-ADDRESS [enter link description here](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry)